# Primefaces 5.1 issue with showModalDialog creates cookie popup window on IE 10

Tags: primefaces, internet-explorer-10

I have upgraded my application from primefaces 3.4.2 to primefaces 5.1 and
javax.faces-2.1.10 to javax.faces-2.1.29.After up gradation my below application
logic started displaying unwanted cookie popupup i.e "To allow this website to provide information personalized for you.will you allow it to put a small
file(called a cookie) on your computer?".Why with primefaces5.1 jar the cookie popup comes up and with old primefaces jar I didn't get the popup message.

This is clear issue with primefaces new version because if I wont use primefaces tags in "message.xhtml" then cookie popup message won't come.I cant ask clients to change IE settings on their system.

To replicate this issue access below logic through URL "http://ipaddress:port/Example".If you access through localhost in URL then you can't get unwanted cookie popup window.

```
index.jsp
<html>
  <head> 
  <script language="JavaScript">

  function onPageLoad(){    
    var retValue = showModalDialog("message.xhtml", window, "dialogHeight: 570px; dialogWidth: 730px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: No; status: No; modal=yes; scroll: No; unadorned: Yes;");
  }
   </script>
  </head>
<body onLoad="onPageLoad();">
  LOGIN PAGE
  </body>
</html>

message.xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form id="usgMessageForm">
                <table width="98%" style="padding-left:2%; padding-top:10px;" border="0" >
                <tr>
                <td style="width: 370px;" align="right">
                                        HELLO USER MESSAGE
                                    </td>
                </tr>
                    </table>
            </h:form>   

    </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout> 
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: The showModalDialog is not a PF functionality I presume. And if not, how can we ever (try to) replicate... What if you display the 'dialog.xhtml' separately?

Comment: is the p:layout part of the 'problem'? What if you remove that?

Comment: If you use any primefaces tags then u will get it